# How to define a type once and assign it to a function and a component in React TypeScript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I have a `types.ts` in which the types of a Redux action are defined, a `Screen.tsx` in which a component which uses the action and a `Actions.ts` in which the action is defined. I want to be able to define the type of an action once and use it in both the `Actions` and `Screen` files for consistency and reducing redundancy. How do I do it?

`types.ts`:

```
export type ConfigActionType = {
  fetchUiConfig: (channelUiConfigUrl: string, callback: () => void) => void
};
```

---

`Screen.tsx`:

```
import {ConfigActionType} from '../types';
interface SplashProps extends ConfigActionType { channelUIConfigURL: string }
const SplashScreen: React.FC<SplashProps> = ({channelUIConfigURL, fetchUiConfig}) = {};
```

---

`Actions.ts`:

```
export const fetchUiConfig = (channelUiConfigUrl, callback) => dispatch => {}
```

---

Like in this example, `fetchUiConfig` type would be once in the `types` file and used in both `Actions` and `Screens`. How do I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could declare and export it separately from `ConfigActionType`:

```
export type FetchUiConfigType = (channelUiConfigUrl: string, callback: () => void) => void;
export type ConfigActionType = {
  fetchUiConfig: FetchUiConfigType
};
```

Then in `Screen.tsx`:

```
import {ConfigActionType} from '../types';
interface SplashProps extends ConfigActionType { channelUIConfigURL: string }
const SplashScreen: React.FC<SplashProps> = ({channelUIConfigURL, fetchUiConfig}) = {};
```

and `Actions.ts`:

```
export const fetchUiConfig: FetchUiConfigType = (channelUiConfigUrl, callback) => dispatch => {};
```

---

Another option is to extract it from `ConfigActionType` where you need it via `ConfigActionType["fetchUiConfig"]`:

```
export const fetchUiConfig: ConfigActionType["fetchUiConfig"] = (channelUiConfigUrl, callback) => dispatch => {}
```

...but it's probably harder to read.